magento2.4.7-p3 capture(admin/sales/order_invoice/capture/invoice_id/....) 404 error
I'm encountering a 404 error while trying to capture an invoice in Magento 2.4.7-p3. The issue seems to be related to the Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Capture controller class, which implements the Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface. This is enforced in Magento 2.4.7, causing the controller to only accept POST requests instead of GET, resulting in a 404 error when accessing the capture URL via GET. How can I resolve this issue and ensure the capture works correctly?
[2024-10-23T11:19:15.988792+00:00] main.DEBUG: URI '/admin/sales/order_invoice/capture/invoice_id/13/key/66fc284f9fba73dee72712c41806570d612ff18c85b3e92f84fe03d2fd529943/'' cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Capture) [] []
**

Please find my PR I just made: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/39297
You can extract a patch from this URL https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/magento/magento2/pull/39297.patch
I hope this could help.
